# How to sort arrays like given below?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I wanted to know how WordPress uses [wp_add_dashboard_widget()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget) function to add widgets. I made something a little similar to that. I made a variable array that would be global and 2 functions `add_widget()` and `display_widget()`. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$widgets = array();
function add_widget( $array=array() )
{
    global $widgets;
    $widgets[] = $array;
    return;
}

function display_widgets()
{
    global $widgets;
    foreach ($widgets as $widget) {
    ?>


        <h1><?php echo $widget['name']; ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $widget['content']; ?></p>


    <?php
    }   
}
add_widget( $widget_1 );
add_widget( $widget_2 );
add_widget( array( "name" => "Sample", "content" => "A very simple sample!" ) );


display_widgets();

?>
```

So as you guys can see what each function globalizes the `$widget` and then it display or add widgets.

**MY PROBLEM**
Whenever I add widget with this function

`add_widget( array( "name" => "Sample", "content" => "A very simple sample!" ) );`

I want it to get another key and thats the order so it would look something like this:

```
add_widget( array( "name" => "Sample", "content" => "A very simple sample!", "order" => 1 ) );
```

So in `display_widgets()` it sorts the arrays inside it first and then display them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would use usort.  With anonymouse functions (PHP5.3+)

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

Otherwis define the function first...

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}
usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```

Comment: `return $a['order'] - $b['order'];` is this minus sign in between them?

Comment: yes it si. sort order is determined by whether the difference is positive or negative.